# Byte stream and utf-8 in python 3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, wxpython

I am reading a blob from a database which contains a png file.

The blob looks correct and is of a bytes data type. It starts:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x00\x00m\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00J\xbf8B\x00\x00\x00\x06bKGD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf9C\xbb\x7f\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x00\x00\
```

However, when I perform:

```
image = wx.Image(blob)
```

I get the message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It seems to be treating the bytes as a string, but why?

Comment: Oops, this is `wx.Image()`.

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation of `wx.Image()` that you're using? I can't seem to find a constructor that takes a buffer [in the documentation I've found](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#wx.Image)

Comment: I don't see any constructor that takes raw bytes: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#api-class-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wx.Image()` does not support creating an image from a raw byte stream. The class has instead interpreted it as a filename (which must be a string, so it is being decoded).

Wrap your data in a `io.BytesIO()` object; `wx` accepts such objects as streams:

```
import io

image = wx.Image(io.BytesIO(blob))
```