# Store a base64 image in python memory, then retrieve for use in wxpython/PIL

Tags: python, image, memory, wxpython, python-imaging-library

1) I have an image that I converted to a string. It looks like this:

```
bytesimage = b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA.... etc etc
```

2) I can convert it to an 'bytesimage.png' using:

```
def StringToImage(self, stringname, imageoutput):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(stringname)
    imagename = imageoutput
    with open(imagename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(imgdata)
```

3) But then I want to save that image or string to memory to use in wxpython interface *without* needing to save the file. I have seen several related questions where the solution is using *io.BytesIO*, but I just cant connect the steps and both wxpython or PIL don't seem to read the bytes properly.

So to clarify:

- I have a image stored in a string **DONE**
- I can convert that to an image (if needed) but dont want to save it **DONE**
- I need that string OR image (whichever is best) saved to memory **NEEDS SOLVING**
- Then I want to be able to use that image in wxpython (I can open in PIL first if required)

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringIO seems to be the way to go. It allows you to pass the decoded string directly to PIL.

```python
import base64
from PIL import Image
import StringIO

# Banana emoji (JPG) as a b64 string.
b64_img_str = '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'

# Decode back to the original bytes
new_img_str = base64.b64decode(b64_img_str)

# Use StringIO to provide an in-memory buffer that we can use
# to pass the image string to PIL.
sio = StringIO.StringIO(new_img_str)
img = Image.open(sio)

# Display the image
img.show()
```

Comment: Consider adding a link to the documentation of StringIO to aid your answer

Comment: Amazing thank you - only thing I changed was StringIO.StringIO is now io.StringIO in Python 3

Comment: Actually @Kaloth I now have trouble converting that image to a bitmap using:


    `image_file = wx.Image(img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()`


   `overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'PngImageFile'`

Comment: Disregard - I got the final part from this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862214/byte-stream-and-utf-8-in-python-3. Thanks again!